# Using chuser and stopudt without root

Tags: security, unix, user-accounts, aix

I am trying to create a user account that can preform certain commands via command line without having to login as root. The commands I want to run are stopudt, chuser, chpasswd. What I have tried is setting the admin flag to true and putting it in the security group... this allows me to run execute the command but it tells me I do not have permission as seen below:

```
$ chuser account_locked=true ds10
Error changing "account_locked" to "true" : You do not have permission.
```

Is there a way I can create a user account that has access to chuser, stopudt and chpasswd without root access? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. Install and configure sudo package. This will permit you to do the task

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked. I tried to upvote you but my rep is not high enough.

Comment: Don't worry, glad to help you :)